# Set language Level to 8 error is received when map.forEach is used with Lambda Expression in Java 11

Tags: java, lambda, maps, java-11

Set language Level to 8 error is received when map.forEach is used with Lambda Expression in Java 11

I have upgraded my JDK to 11 from 8, my existing project is showing compilation errors with lambda expressions for Map. Below is code

```
 public void validateHeaders(Map<String, String> headers) {
        headers.forEach((key, value) -> Assert.assertEquals(value, response.getHeader(key)));

    }
```

[image: IntellijIDE Error]

Comment: Are you using Eclipse or IntelliJ?

Comment: I am using Inteliij IDE